# CQWP : slider rendering two images per item

Tags: 2013, item-styles, cswp, image-rendition

I'm coming up with a huuuuge subject : rendering an image Slider in a CQWP (SP2013, but Standard Edition, so no CSWP)

So, i'm trying to create my "HomePage Slider" item template.
I'm using FlexSlider to do so, with help from [pena informatika](https://penainformatika.wordpress.com/2014/08/09/adding-slider-to-a-sharepoint-using-content-by-query-web-part-cqwp/) and some other tutorials.

**What i want to do :** Create a slider wich displays the main Image (a "Image with publication..." column), and in the caption, display the Title (with a link to the page), the Sub-Title (a custom Text field). **AND** the caption has to be styled with a background image, which is a custom "image with publication..." column called Pictogramme.

So i've got several questions :

**1 - How to say "hey, caption, get the Pictogramme to be your background image!" ?**
You can see in my code  `<div class="flex-caption" style="background-image:url({@SafePictoUrl})">` : that does not work.

**2 - How can i have my main image displayed?**
When looking for the dom, my image's src is empty. so my `<img src="{$SafeImageUrl}"/>` does not work. ***Is there any problem rendering TWO images in the same item?***

**3 - How to display the title of my item in Image title?**
The question says it itself.

**4 - How to modify the rendition id of the pictures?**
I would like to modify the rendition ids of the background image AND the main image. How can i achieve this in ItemStyle.xsl?

Here is my Item template (in ItemStyle.xsl) :

```
<xsl:template name="HomePage-Slider" match="Row[@Style='HomePage-Slider']" mode="itemstyle">

    <xsl:variable name="SafeLinkUrl"><xsl:call-template name="OuterTemplate.GetSafeLink"><xsl:with-param name="UrlColumnName" select="'LinkUrl'"/></xsl:call-template></xsl:variable>
    <xsl:variable name="SafeImageUrl"><xsl:call-template name="OuterTemplate.GetSafeStaticUrl"><xsl:with-param name="UrlColumnName" select="'ImageUrl'"/></xsl:call-template></xsl:variable>
    <xsl:variable name="DisplaySstitre"><xsl:value-of select="@Sous-titre"/></xsl:variable>
    <xsl:variable name="SafePictoUrl"><xsl:value-of select="@Pictogramme"/></xsl:variable>
    <xsl:variable name="Titre"><xsl:value-of select="@Title"/></xsl:variable>

    <li>
        <a href="{$SafeLinkUrl}">
            <xsl:if test="$ItemsHaveStreams = 'True'"><xsl:attribute name="onclick"><xsl:value-of select="@OnClickForWebRendering"/></xsl:attribute></xsl:if>
            <xsl:if test="$ItemsHaveStreams != 'True' and @OpenInNewWindow = 'True'"><xsl:attribute name="onclick"><xsl:value-of disable-output-escaping="yes" select="$OnClickTargetAttribute"/></xsl:attribute></xsl:if>
            <img src="{$SafeImageUrl}" title="{@Titre}">
                <xsl:if test="$ImageWidth != ''"><xsl:attribute name="width"><xsl:value-of select="$ImageWidth" /></xsl:attribute></xsl:if>
                <xsl:if test="$ImageHeight != ''"><xsl:attribute name="height"><xsl:value-of select="$ImageHeight" /></xsl:attribute></xsl:if>
            </img>
        </a>
        <div class="flex-caption" style="background-image:url({@SafePictoUrl})">
            <xsl:call-template name="OuterTemplate.CallPresenceStatusIconTemplate"/>
            <p><b><xsl:value-of select="$Titre"/></b></p>
            <p><xsl:value-of select="$DisplaySstitre" disable-output-escaping="yes"/></p>
        </div>
        <p><xsl:value-of select="$SafePictoUrl" disable-output-escaping="yes"/></p>
    </li>

</xsl:template>
```

Thanks a lot everybody!